# Django messaging & template inheritance - how to use it?

Tags: django, django-templates

First of all: Hello StackOverflow folks :) . That's my first post here. Okay, on to the thing: The Django messaging framework does not work in my little application. I have the following layout:

- base.html -> index.html (inherits from base.html)
- an importcsv view (which does nothing yet, but wants to go back to index.html and display a message there, like "import successful")
- a basically vanilla django 1.3, os x
- the template inheritance works quite nicely

And however I tried, I cannot get messaging to work. I basically copied-and-pasted the examples from the Django docs, but to no avail.

On to the code.

base.html (shortened to the essentials):

```html
<html>
<head>
    {% block extra-css %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

views.py: (rtr is simply "import render_to_response as rtr")

```py
def _importlegs(request):
    f = request.FILES['file']
    print "_importlegs"
    messages.info(request, "Test")
    return rtr('index.html', RequestContext(request))
```

The result is, that the "messages" block is never, ever displayed. No matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the messages middleware is in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and that `django.contrib.messages` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. If it wasn't, do a syncdb afterwards so that the messages tables get created in your databse.

Also, try making `{}` the second argument to `rtr` so that `RequestContext(request)` is the third.

Comment: so, tested that, didn't work. The configuration was completely enabled from the start (nevertheless did a syncdb), and neither `rtr("..", {}, RC(request))`, nor `rtr("..", RC(request))` do work. Thanks anyhow. Any more ideas? :) ... I also removed the template inheritance, just to be sure, for a test run - no effect.

Comment: What if you try doing `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`? You could also try setting the message with `message.info` but not iterating through the messages, but instead just putting `{% debug %} somewhere in your template and then seeing if the `messages` variable is present in your context.

Comment: Progress. I added `{% debug %}` to my template and changed the message to "yadda". No trace of that in the whole text that appeared, nor could I find a "messages" variable. Now I really have no clue of what's going on. After that I simply set some properties in the context dict, and ... well, also nowhere to be seen. Supergreat. It's getting kind of frustrating. But thanks, you _are_ helping me! (even if it's only in little steps right now ;)

Comment: Ah, interesting. So it seems that the context isn't getting passed correctly to your templates, and it isn't a problem with either messages or template inheritance. Very strange indeed.

Comment: Intresting maybe. But no fun :( ... I have postponed the issue now and concentrate on some other functionality. Maybe inspiration will hit me.

Comment: WTF? Okay that is voodoo. The function `importlegs` is called from the actual view function - it is not the view itself.

Comment: ... Now I moved the code out of the function into the actual view - tadaa, works. I am quite speechless and pretty ... well, non-good-mooded. I have absolutely no idea what happens here.